# Spawning Enemies In Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I'm looking to make multiple spawn points all around a 2d top-down map for different enemies to spawn form, I have created the game objects for the spawn points and have created a script to spawn enemies (it's an old script I've tweaked from a 2d frogger game I created) however my enemies don't seem to spawn from the spawn point or even spawn at all can anyone give me any advice as to why this is.

This is my Spawner Scirpt

```
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemySpawn1 : MonoBehaviour {

public float spawnDelay = 0.3f;

public GameObject Enemy1;

public Transform[] spawnPoints;

float nextTimeToSpawn = 0.2f;

void Update ()
{
    if (nextTimeToSpawn <= Time.time)
    {
        SpawnZombie();
        nextTimeToSpawn = Time.time + spawnDelay;
    }
}

void SpawnZombie ()
{
    int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length);
    Transform spawnPoint = spawnPoints[randomIndex];

    Instantiate(Enemy1, spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation);
}

}
```

the prefab for my enemy is called 'Enemy1'

Comment: It all looks like it would work after initial glance, are you positive that SpawnZombie runs? Try putting a flag (console log) in the method and seeing if it prints.

Comment: I don't see any error here, are you sure that the script is attached to an active object, and that the script itself is enabled?

Comment: Yeah its attached to an active object and the script is definitely enabled I just can understand why it won't spawn my enemies

Comment: Did you add data to your spawnPoints array?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Well you need to have the spawnPoints array filled with at least 1 piece of data or else there won't be anywhere for the Zombie to spawn. This should be done by clicking on the object and adding some values to the spawnPoints array

Comment: Yeah ive done that

Comment: Are you getting any errors anywhere? Or are the Zombies just not appearing?

Comment: No errors just warnings and the zombies dont appear at all, These are the warnings

Comment: The referenced script (Unknown) on this Behaviour is missing!
UnityEngine.Object:Instantiate(GameObject, Vector3, Quaternion)
EnemySpawn1:SpawnZombie() (at Assets/Scripts/EnemySpawn1.cs:27)
EnemySpawn1:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/EnemySpawn1.cs:17)

Comment: It sounds like the reference to the script is missing. Maybe try deleting the scripts you have on your objects and re-adding them. (Make sure to take note/screenshot of your settings beforehand)

Comment: Ive done that also and still dont get any spawning

Comment: Just so I understand the setup, you have the above script, EnemySpawn1, attached to a controller object (or any object) in the scene. You also have a prefab that is being referenced in the script EnemySpawn1, as GameObject Enemy1 and that prefab is the Zombie you want to spawn. Is all that correct?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Did you try the flag method I suggested earlier? Try adding: Debug.Log("Enemy spawned!"); somewhere in the SpawnZombie method.

Comment: I'd say to also add a flag to the `Start` method to make sure the script is getting instantiated at all.

Comment: What is `Enemy1` and how is it getting populated?